# executing mailx command in shell script

Tags: shell, mailx

I have a simple shell script that executes a .sql script.  When the .sql script has completed, the shell script sends an email to a specified address notifying whether or not the .sql script ran successfully.

My problem is that the subject line is being truncated.  I am using a simple IF statement to determine the subject line:

```
grep 'ORA-' $OUTFILE > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? = 1 ]; then
    ERRORS=n
    SUBJECT= "$VERSION script successful"
else
    ERRORS=y
    SUBJECT="$VERSION script had error(s)"
fi
```

This works fine.  However, when I execute the mailx command, the subject line is truncated to "Development" or "Production" depending on the version of the script that has been executed:

```
mailx -s $SUBJECT $EMAIL < $MAILFILE
```

I know the subject line needs to be in double quotes if it includes embedded spaces, but this does not seem to work correctly when assigned to a variable.

Is there a way around this?  Is there a way to escape the double quotes

Answer (score 7):

You need to quote `$SUBJECT` as you use it, i.e.

```
mailx -s "$SUBJECT" $EMAIL < $MAILFILE
```

Also there should be no space in

```
SUBJECT="$VERSION script successful"
```

Comment: It seems to work (mostly) when I do this: "${SUBJECT}".  However, since the $SUBJECT is being assigned a string as a variable ($VERSION), the string is now "$VERSION script successful" or "$VERSION script had error(s)".  Any idea how to get the variable $VERSION to resolve as a string?

Comment: 1. I note that you have a space in one of your assignments, like `SUBJECT= "....". 2. The behaviour you describe sounds like you reall have single quotes on your assignment, i.e. `SUBJECT='...'`. Going to bed now. Will check in the morning. Good luck.